# codeigniter pagination customizing

Tags: html, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I am browsing trough the CI documentation particularly http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html .

First thing that was stuck in my mind was "CodeIgniter's Pagination class is very easy to use, and it is 100% customizable, either dynamically or via stored preferences." but there always but something.

My pagination is as following `Previous 1 2 3 4 ... n Next` now for each of these I can create opening html tags and closing html tags in my controller.

For ex:

Previous

```
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<div class="previous">';

The opening tag for the "previous" link.
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</div>';
```

Next

```
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<div>';

The opening tag for the "next" link.
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</div>';
```

And for Last first etc. Now in my design I made Previous float left Next float right and I have a `<div class="middle_pager">` which holds all page numbers together in the middle.

From what I see in the documentation I don't have a option in CI to put all page numbers in between html tags, I only have option to put each page number inside some tags, maybe there is a way but I missed a point. Anybody can help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is, that you have to think out of the box.

You should add a an opening tag to the end of of your "prev_tag_close"

```
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<div class="previous">';

The opening tag for the "previous" link.
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</div>**<opening tag>**';
```

and a closing tag at your "next_tag_open" like

```
$config['next_tag_open'] = '**</opening tag>**<div>';

The opening tag for the "next" link.
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</div>';
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

That hardly resolves the problem, how would you deal with this situation on the first and last page? The next_tag_open/close would not appear on the final page of the pagination and the prev_tag_open/close would not appear on the first page of pagination.

This will obviously cause both of the block elements for these pages to break

Ok so I had this same problem earlier today and it was really doing my head in. The only solution I came up with (works prefectly) is this;

Create a div around the output -

```
<div class="pagination2">
    <?php echo $link; ?>
</div>
```

Then use the pagination tags provided by the class around use these tags to wrap around the digit tags (num_tag_open/close).

`$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<p>;
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</p>';`

Now jump into css and relatively position the outer block element pagination2, then go and absolutely position the inner block class pagination, center it and then you can use a negative value to push the absolutely positioned nextlink or prevlink elements however you wish. See below for css I used.

```
 .pagination2{
  position: relative;
  right: -10px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;    
  outline:none;
  }

  .pagination{
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 120px;
  }

  .pagination-button-previous{   
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -160px;
    width: 74px;
    height: 24px;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Thanks for completing this answer.